# PHP filter and sort by min amount

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a display package page with php and mysql. There're 10 buttons on top of the table to refilter the output. How I did the refilter is by using `$_GET['command']` which is equal to '`AND lock_in_period = '1yr'`. I've tried to save `$_GET['command']` under session, but it doesn't work. The problem now is I can't get the min loan amount to sort asc or desc after I refilter the output.

**output**

[image]

**mysql query:**

```
if($property_type_search == 'HDB'){
    $find=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM package_creation WHERE property_type IN ('HDB','HDB,Private') $newcommand ORDER BY $columnname $order");
}
```

**min loan amount sorting button:**

```
<a class="link_style" href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?command=<?php echo $_GET['command']?>&columnname= min_loan_amount&<?php if($_GET['sort']== "asc"){echo "sort=desc"; $_GET['sort']="asc";}elseif($_GET['sort']=="desc"){echo "sort=asc";$_GET['sort']="desc";}elseif($_GET['sort']==""){echo "sort=asc";}?>"><img src="images/arrow_sort.png"></a>
```

**Refilter buttons:**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_GET['FC']=='1'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND lock_in_period = 'N.A' AND interest_rate_type IN ('Floating Rate(Sibor/Sor Rate)','Floating Rate(Sibor Rate)')");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='2'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND lock_in_period = '1yr' AND interest_rate_type IN ('Floating Rate(Sibor/Sor Rate)','Floating Rate(Sibor Rate)')");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='3'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND lock_in_period = '2yrs' AND interest_rate_type IN ('Floating Rate(Sibor/Sor Rate)','Floating Rate(Sibor Rate)')");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='4'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND lock_in_period = '3yrs' AND interest_rate_type IN ('Floating Rate(Sibor/Sor Rate)','Floating Rate(Sibor Rate)')");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='5'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND yrs_of_fixed_rate = '1yr' AND interest_rate_type = 'Fixed Rate'");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='6'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND yrs_of_fixed_rate = '2yrs' AND interest_rate_type = 'Fixed Rate'");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='7'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND yrs_of_fixed_rate = '3yrs' AND interest_rate_type = 'Fixed Rate'");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='8'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND yrs_of_fixed_rate = '4yrs' AND interest_rate_type = 'Fixed Rate'");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='9'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND yrs_of_fixed_rate = '5yrs' AND interest_rate_type = 'Fixed Rate'");
}
if($_GET['FC']=='10'){
header("location:rates_results.php?command=AND installation_mode IN ('Saving offset interest','Interest and Principle,Saving offset interest','Interest only, Saving offset interest','Interest and Principle,Interest only,Saving offset interest')");
}
?>
```

**inject to mysql query:**

```
$columnname ="";
if($_GET['columnname']){
$columnname = $_GET['columnname'];  
}

if($columnname==""){
$columnname="first_year";   
}
if($order==""){
$order = "desc";    
}
$order=$_GET['sort'];

$newcommand = "";
if($_GET['command'] !=""){
$newcommand = $_GET['command']; 
}
```

Comment: How are you passing `$_GET['sort']` to your query? Also, beware that `$_GET['command']` is wide open to SQL injection attack

Comment: Still thinking of a way to solve that too..

Comment: You are setting `$order` to `$_GET['order']` (don't see where this var comes from), then overwriting it with `$_GET['sort']`. Better perhaps to do `$order = (isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'desc';` - Although this may not actually solve your problem is less prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

Check this LOC --

```
command=$_GET['command'] and make it as command=<?php echo $_GET['command'] ?>
```

Comment: @Psinyee ohh okk let me check it more

Comment: @Psinyee are you sure header URLs are working correctly ? use exit; after header() and let me know if it solves your issue or not..sanitize the data before making any query to the db

Comment: the header is working correctly. After I refilter and click on the sort button the $_GET['command'] will disappear.

Comment: @Psinyee disappear or No value ???? what error its throwing, what URL its forming and what is your desired URL ? I think you need to make AJAX call without sending new http headers.. thats why info is getting lost .. :) Hope these things will make sense to u :)